# Protractor defaultTimeoutInterval doesn't work properly

Tags: protractor, timeout

in my

> protractor.conf

file among the other paramteres I have these 3 timeouts:

> allScriptsTimout
>
> getPageTimeout
>
> defaultTimeoutInterval

So the problem it that when I set

> defaultTimeoutInterval=2000

or

> defaultTimeoutInterval=13000

then protractor respects it  and even if something last longer period of time  I get:

> Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 13000
>   milliseconds

or

> Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 25000
>   milliseconds

but if I set a bigger number like around 25000 and higher then I always receive error:

> Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000
>   milliseconds

Why is it set to 5sec in that cases? My tests fail because of that :)
Can you please help?